# Nested relation such as $member->assigner->name from one table

Tags: laravel, relationship

I am trying to achieve a relation of relation (or something such as) from a table with user_id (assignee) and assigner_id (assigner) in table task_assigns.

Tried many relation options, however can't get my head around it.

I have tried **hasOne()** and **hasOneThrough()** however it does not seem to work as i am sure i'm not doing it the right way.

Target is to display Task, assigned members and who assigned each member in particular task.

So Task (model) has many members:

```php
public function members()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'task_assigns');
}
```

So $task->members() obviously reads **user_id** from **task_assigns**

Table **task_assigns** has columns:

```
| id | task_id | user_id | assigner_id |
|----|---------|---------|-------------|
| 1  | 12      | 1       | 7           |
| 2  | 12      | 2       | 8           |
| 3  | 10      | 1       | 2           |
```

Which should mean - each task assignee has one assigner.

And in my view i list $task->members this way

```
@foreach($task->members as $member)
    {{ $member->name }} (assigned by: [who?])
@endforeach
```

In final result i have

```
Task #12

John (assigned by: ??)
Pete (assigned by: ??)
```

My aim is to display who assigned each member in task, however i can't get it done..

Comment: You can load nested relations like this: `Task::with('members.assigner')->get()`.

Comment: @MartinBean yes, but how do i form the assigner relation ? That is my question.

Comment: Your `Task` model would have a `members` relation, and your `Member` model would have an `assigner` relation. Laravel will then traverse the models. You don’t need to associate the `Task` model with an assigner.

Comment: @MartinBean please explain with example. thank you.

Comment: I’m just explaining what is already covered in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it eventually.

Now TaskModel hasMany assigns and TaskAssign has members. That way i call them in view this way:

```
{{ $task->assign->member->name }}
```